# Как можно вставить в файл excel формулы автоматический

Tags: python, excel, автоматизация

Есть такая проблема, есть файл excel который каждый день обновляется,надо как-то в этот файл вставлять автоматический 2 формулы в 2 столбца(соответственно) с протяжкой(в формулах есть адресации к ячейкам, чтобы в ячейки были соответственно).Желательно чтоб через командную строку потому что остальные задачи с файлом происходит через нее.Есть способ как это сделать, желательно с примерами(ну или ответом:) ).[image: Пример таблицы, в конце видны формулы]

Нашел способ как можно редактировать таблицы через python(openpyxl) но при попытке вставить формулы после открытия файла выходит попытка восстановления и после восстановления формулы удаляются потому что они вызывают ошибку но если ввести их в ручную то все норм(но нужно чтобы было автоматический)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все нашел способ как это можно решить есть плагин для python-openpyxl через него можно редактировать таблицы, если вы хотите вставить формулы то надо использовать английское название формулы и вместо знаков препинания(точка с запитой) надо использовать просто **запитую**.А если нужно использовать десятичные числа типа 1,2 то надо вводить 1.2.